# $E$-$k$ diagram of valence band

Tags: energy, momentum, solid-state-physics, dispersion

Why is that the E-K diagram of the valence band is bending downward? Namely, why is that the E (energy) of valence band is Ev '-' kinetic energy while the E (energy) of conduction band is Ec '+' kinetic energy?

Is the kinetic energy of a hole negative?

[image]

Comment: See the book of Kittel for a nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

That expression $E=E_v-\frac{p^2}{2m_p}$ comes out from the Taylor expansion of the energy in maximum point of the band, the minus sign is due to the concavity of the curve that it has a negative second derivative.
Generally me redefine the value of the mass, we recall it effective mass, and we interpret the minus sign like an hole-like behavior. I hope my explanation was clear